# Accessing audio files from an array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dynamic, html5-audio

I am trying to add an audio aspect to a HTML/JavaScript quiz (see JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/55aJt/3/). I have an empty audio tag:

```
<audio id="myAudio" src="" controls></audio>
```

which I want to play from my array 'question' property:

```
var allQuestions = [{
    question: "http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3",
    choices: ["3rd", "5th", "4th"],
    correctAnswer: 2
},
```

This isn't working as my audio player doesn't load anything. My function to send the data from the object to the audio player is obviously wrong in some way. Can someone help shed a bit of light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: why not just add a new property to each question object with data to send to the audio player for each question?

Comment: Yeah that's what I've been trying (and failing) to do! What I have now is much closer I think. I'll update my question...

Comment: I answered the question below. Let me know if it works for you and if so... please accept it (check the check mark). If not leave a comment and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the complete answer but see if it gets you in the right direction.

http://jsfiddle.net/55aJt/9/

Basically you can change the audio.src via javascript. So I just replaced it with an object property that changes when the user clicks the next button. The first src defaults to the initial src of the audio tag. You can modify the code if you like but I figure it might be fine as is.

```
var allQuestions = [{
    question: "Identify the musical interval",
    choices: ["3rd", "5th", "4th"],
    correctAnswer: 2,
    audioSrc: " defaults to the original .ogg file"

}, {
    question: "Which of the following best describes this chord?",
    choices: ["Major", "Minor", "Diminished"],
    correctAnswer: 0,
    audioSrc:" http://en.wikiaudio.org/images/b/b8/MPC60_626_Cym_da_China_.wav"

}];
```

**Then**

```
function nextQuestion() {
    updateScore();
    questionCount++;
    showScore();
    showQuestion();
    var audio = document.getElementById('myAudio')
    audio.src = ( allQuestions[questionCount].audioSrc);




}
```

Comment: Yep, it works! It's an interesting way of going about it. It might be problematic in the future if I wanted to randomize the order of the questions, but for now it's fine. Thanks!

Comment: You could fix that by setting the audio src on page load to whatever allQuestions[0].audioSrc is.